# iOS / Windows Store App: can I know whether my other app installed on this device/user account?

Tags: ios, xamarin, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have several apps and I want to know from app A whether app B or C are installed. In Android I can check does package exist, but is there something like this in iOS and windows store app? I'm using Xamarin for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS you can get your apps to confirm unique URL schemes and check whether they can be opened.

References:

URL schemes - https://www.appcoda.com/working-url-schemes-ios/

Can open url - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIApplication.CanOpenUrl/p/Foundation.NSUrl/

Answer (score 1):

You can use system Keychain to achieve this. 
Values in system Keychain can be shared between collection of apps and you can set values like `isAppBExists` and `isAppCExists` to true/false in this apps. And then check this values in app A

[Link to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I understand after user uninstalled app this value will survive.

Comment: Yes, you right value will be available if user uninstall the app. Perhaps using custom URL scheme in answer below will be a better solution

Answer (score 1):

For UWP app, you can use [PackageManager.FindPackagesForUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackagesforuser) Method to find all packages installed for the specified user.

See the following similar topic:

[how to get list of all installed apps and run them in UWP WinRT 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170492/how-to-get-list-of-all-installed-apps-and-run-them-in-uwp-winrt-8-1)

[Get List of installed windows apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160159/get-list-of-installed-windows-apps)